# Django overwrite existing db backend

Tags: python, django, postgresql, inet

I am using Python `2.7.5`, Django `1.5.4` and PostgreSQL `9.3`. I have a INET field in my model object. The field definition is like;

```
class INETField(_NetAddressField):
    description = "PostgreSQL INET field"
    max_length = 39
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'inet'

    def python_type(self):
        return IPNetwork

    def form_class(self):
        return InetAddressFormField
```

All we need to know here, the field type is `inet`. Everything is perfect until this point.

But when I try to filter by `inet field`, Although there must some results,  there is no result filtered as result. So I looked at the query that is generated by `Django`. It is like;

```
SELECT
    ......
    ......
FROM "ip_prefix"
WHERE (HOST("ip_prefix"."prefix") :: TEXT LIKE '%0.0.0.0/0%' AND "ip_prefix"."vrf_id" = 1 AND "ip_prefix"."afi" = '4')
ORDER BY "ip_prefix"."prefix" ASC
```

So I saw the problem that HOST method of PostgreSQL gives the host part of the ip not with netmask (0.0.0.0). So I needed to find where the part is generated. I searched and I found it in `postgresql_psycopg2/operations`. The part was;

```
def field_cast_sql(self, db_type):
    if db_type == 'inet':
        return 'HOST(%s)'
    return '%s'
```

**My question is not about** inet field or specific things like ips, network etc. **My question is,** "Is there a way to overwrite some part of existing `db backend` in `Django` without forking the library?". If I could do this, I can make it like;

```
def field_cast_sql(self, db_type):
    if db_type == 'inet':
        return 'NETWORK(%s)'
    return '%s'
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? HOST is incredibly slow with Postgres ...